# why don't add template support for pure C?

Tags: c, templates

Somebody beleives we can acheive good structure of code with template meta programming, without object-orient method. 
So can we just add template support to C, to make C more powerful without losing the runtime effieciency?

Comment: We don't write the C compilers buddy :P

Comment: Noone forces you to make use of object-oriented methods when programming C++. So why not use that?

Comment: We did, it’s called C++. Templates without some of the other things C++ offers would be quite useless.

Answer (score 3):

It already happened. The feature of type generic primary expression with `_Generic` that is new to C11 is basically that.

Comment: That's a bit of an overstatement, but yes, `_Generic` is somewhat similar.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes what did you expect from the author of P99. lol

Comment: And `_Generic` is kind of a hell to read and write when your function takes multiple parameters.

Comment: @Morwenn, aggreed, even for one single parameter. It is not supposed to be used directly in user code but to go into macros, I think.

Comment: _Generic is preprocessor conditional, it has nothing to do with meta programming.

Comment: No, `_Generic` is not a preprocessor directive, but a primary expression. It works with types, the preprocessing phase knows nothing about that.